# service and manifest files

Tags: java, android, xml, manifest

i wrote this code in android studio , it wont show me the toast message :
here is the manifest file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="31">


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".BoradCastReciever"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

and here is the java code class reciever :

```
package com.mohapp.myapplication;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class BoradCastReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean is_on = intent.getBooleanExtra("air", false);
        if (is_on == true) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Air Plane mode is on", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(context, "Air Plane mode is false", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

i am using API 33 with Gradle version 7.5 and Embedd JDK(jdk 11)

Answer (score 1):

From the official android docs :

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions

> As part of the Android 8.0 (API level 26) Background Execution Limits,
> apps that target the API level 26 or higher can no longer register
> broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest.
> However, several broadcasts are currently exempted from these
> limitations. Apps can continue to register listeners for the following
> broadcasts, no matter what API level the apps target.

So **"android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE"** is no longer in the list of exempted broadcasts. You cannot receive the broadcast from a broadcast receiver. So you must register your broadcast receiver in activity rather than in AndroidManifest.

Answer (score 0):

In API 30 and plus , it uses the java code more than manifest file and xml files
use onStart and onStop method and add intent inside and use this.register(obj claa of reciever) and unregister on stop method